# I intend to define and use a setter normally in Dart, but I get an error : The method 'setAnimal' isn't defined for the type 'AnimalCage'

Tags: dart

```
void main(){

  Animal a1 = Animal();
  Cat c1 = Cat();

  AnimalCage ac1 = AnimalCage();

  ac1.setAnimal(a1); //error: The method 'setAnimal' isn't defined for the type 'AnimalCage'.


}

class AnimalCage{
  Animal? _animal;

  set setAnimal(Animal animal){
    print('animals setter');
    _animal = animal;
  }
}

class Animal {

}
```

I get the above error, but I don't know what's wrong.

Is there something wrong with using the setter?

If I define setAnimal as a method, the error will disappear, but I think there is no problem with the setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `setAnimal` is a setter, you don't use it like a method.

Simply do:

```
ac1.setAnimal = a1;
```

To avoid confusion, you shouldn't prefix your setter names with `set`, just use the name of whatever you want to set like so:

```
set animal(Animal animal){
    print('animals setter');
    _animal = animal;
  }
```

Then use the setter like so:

```
ac1.animal = a1;
```

If you really want to use the method syntax, then create a method instead, like so:

```
void setAnimal(Animal animal){
    print('animals setter');
    _animal = animal;
  }
```

Then you can use it:

```
ac1.setAnimal(a1);
```